# How to add a custom fields created in Employee Module to Leave Request Module in openerp 8?

Tags: odoo

I had created two new fields in for Employee Model via the database structure and modified the form view of employee model to display both the fields. They are displaying perfectly. Now I want to refer to these new fields in the Leave Request Module. I don't know how to display it. I tried adding it similarly like I did for Employee Model but it doesn't help. Could you help in achieving this?

Comment: Please give some sample from you form definition. How this Leave Request module is related to the Employee module? I suppose you use wrong reference to your fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the code you've got so far?
are you using xpath?
this might be the solulation for your problem.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='thenameofthefieldfromcurrentview']" position="after">
     <field name="thenameofthefieldyouwanthere"/>
</xpath>
```